# Composing Global Classes in CSS Modules from SCSS

Tags: css, css-modules

How do I compose from a global class in CSS Modules, when writing in SCSS?

According to (my understanding of) CSS Module's [Composing from global class names](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#composing-from-global-class-names) documentation, the following should work:

```css
:global {
  .bar {
    color: purple;
  }
}

.my-icon {
  composes: bar from global;
}
```

But I receive the following error:

`referenced class name "bar" in composes not found`

How can I change the above to properly compose from a global class?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
:global(.bar) {
  color: red;
}

.myIcon {
  composes: bar from global;
}
```

Here is a link to a sandbox I created with a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/css-modules-global-s25r8j?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6tsodn00063b6i7rshk4jk%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6tsodn00023b6is4jzzcrl%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6tsodn00033b6iss8bujf4%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6tsodn00053b6i7p8mvypg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq6tsodn00023b6is4jzzcrl%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6tsodn00023b6is4jzzcrl%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6vix7z00023b6ilgxqfclk%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A13%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A13%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq6vix7z00023b6ilgxqfclk%2522%257D%252C%2522clq6tsodn00053b6i7p8mvypg%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6tsodn00043b6is9y7p8sg%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6tsodn00053b6i7p8mvypg%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq6tsodn00043b6is9y7p8sg%2522%257D%252C%2522clq6tsodn00033b6iss8bujf4%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6tsodn00033b6iss8bujf4%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried to sign out first and then access the link, and I was able to. I think you should be able to as well. 

I also added screenshots to the main answer with what you will find when trying to access this link.